# Array of input values where id contains specific text - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here:

```
$('*[id*=ask]:visible').each(function questions() {
    pollQuestions = $(this).val();
  });
```

This only displays the latest input's value from a row of inputs. (I am appending more inputs with a click). I want instead an array of all inputs' values. 
The appended inputs have id's like 'id="ask[1]"', 'id="ask[2]"', etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code creates empty array first and then push new value into it.

```
var pollQuestions = [];
$('*[id*=ask]:visible').each(function questions() {
    pollQuestions.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: although Scimonster's solution with `.map()` is more elegant

Comment: For me your's is easier for my ajax calls

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this by just using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
$('*[id*=ask]:visible').map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
  }).get();
```

Your existing code would set a variable and overwrite it each time, which is why only the last one would stay.